# I can use simplexml_load_file on an URL but if I save it, it won't load

Tags: xml, laravel, storage

If I load a file using `simplexml_load_file($URL)`, the file loads without a problem.

However, when I try to load it from local, using:

```php
simplexml_load_file(Storage::get('public/XML/myfile.xml'))
```

I get the error:

> simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

The file exists, as the `Storage::exists()` method returns `true` and if I write in the Artisan tinker console, `Storage::get('public/XML/myfile.xml')`, the file will be returned.

I am saving my file using:

```php
Storage::put('public/XML/myfile.xml', file_get_contents($URL));
```

Comment: Try this method `simplexml_load_string(Storage::get('public/XML/myfile.xml'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file()` interprets an XML file (either a file on your disk or a URL) into an object.

But in your case you want interpret the content of the file => string of XML into an object for that you can use [simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
simplexml_load_string(Storage::get('public/XML/myfile.xml'))‌​;
```